# Allow user one entry in 3 sets of cells (one for each table)

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 tables and one each one of them I only want to allow 1 cell with 1.

This is what I got so far.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim rLook As Range
    Set rLook = Range("A1:C1")
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    If Intersect(Target, rLook) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If wf.CountA(rLook) < 2 Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Target.Clear
        MsgBox "Only one entry allowed"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This works for 3 cells but i got tables with several rows.

How can I work this?

Comment: Are your tables formatted as tables (i.e. are they a `ListObject`)?

Comment: @BigBen I don't, I only have like range (A2:G28)

Comment: Do you only allow one cell per row, or one cell per table?

Comment: @BigBen one per table

Comment: Then just change the range to `A2:G28`.